# INSERT INTO mysqli not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I cannot seem to get this inserting. nothing inserts at all. I have tried this a couple of ways now but neither work. the connection to the db is there but no insert.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO 
              friendshipTable
             ( user_a_memberID , user_b_memberID )
             VALUES ($member_id,$addFriendID)";  
 $resultx = mysqli_query($connExt, $insert);
```

[image: Table]

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/yLa52dyn/)

Comment: Try seeing what `mysqli_error($connExt)` says

Comment: And what is the value of `$resultx`?

Comment: echo the query string and run sql in database and see what happen

Comment: The comment you've added below the answer implies that your table has four columns; your INSERT is only adding two columns. Could you add the table structure, too, please?

Comment: @EngCy when i echo $resultx nothing happens. its empty.

Comment: @StuartWickenden echo your `$insert` variable not `$resultx`.

Comment: echo $insert string and run manually in db

Comment: @StuartWickenden:  **`echo $insert;`** after you assign the value to `$insert`. Take that SQL statement to another client, and test it. Also, do a conditional test on $resultx, if it's FALSE, **`echo mysqli_error($connExt);`**   (The code appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection, unless you've made sure the variables included in the SQL text are "safe" by properly escaping them. The preferred pattern is to use **prepared statement** with **bind placeholders**.  .

Comment: you need to pass `datetime_followed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
There is no problem with query actually its taking $connExt as undefined because its a scope issue. you can use `global $connExt;` in your local function 
or code as below...

```
<form action="friendship.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="addfriend" placeholder="add friend">
    <input type="text" name="member_id" placeholder="member id">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php


$connExt = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}


if ( isset($_POST['addfriend']) && $_POST['addfriend']) {
    $addFriend = $_POST['addfriend'];
    $member_id = $_POST['member_id'];
    addFriend($addFriend, $member_id, $connExt);
}

function addFriend($addFriendID, $member_id, $connExt) { //add friend acts as a follow based system
    //create db query

    $insert = "INSERT INTO friendshipTable( user_a_memberID , user_b_memberID )
                              VALUES ('$member_id','$addFriendID');";

    $resultx = mysqli_query($connExt, $insert);



    echo "addfriend: ".$addFriendID;
    echo '<br />';
    echo "member_id: ".$member_id;
    echo '<br />';
    echo "woop!";
    echo '<br />';
    echo $resultx;;
    //return status

}

function unFriend() {

}




?>
```